# Wordpress.com hosting

Tags: wordpress, shared-hosting, self-hosting, wordpress.com

I've a domain registered on hostmonster.com and my blog is on wordpress.com now how can I transfer my domain to Wordpress(which I think is not possible) or map my domain url to my Wordpress blog.

Note : I don't need self hosting I want to use wordpress.com hosting.

Any idea how can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can have your DNS hosted at Wordpress.com. If that is what you want then you do this -

1. Through your registrar, point your domain to the Wordpress.com DNS servers

   1. Primary DNS Server: NS1.WORDPRESS.COM
   2. Secondary DNS Server: NS2.WORDPRESS.COM
2. Go to the blog you have registered with wordpress.com and log into the dashboard.
3. Click on Store
4. Purchase 'Add a Domain'
5. Click on Settings and then Domains
6. Type the domain name you purchased into the 'Add a domain' field and click 'Add domain to blog'
7. Once domain is added, click 'Edit DNS'

   1. Most of the settings you need will be set by default.
   2. If you have a Google Apps account, you can use this edit interface to add the Verification code they give you for confirming the domain is yours.

Comment: Yes you can host the DNS. Transfer domain on Wordpress is not possible. That means if you bought domain from elsewhere hosting on wordpress.com is not possible. Also I found that you cannot put ads on wordpress.com even if you bought $99 membership. You can put ads on VIP account but they are too much expensive.